# Found a taweez in parents home

Tags: tawiz

Could someone please translate this taweez? My mother randomly found it in her washer recently. It doesn’t belong to any of my siblings. All my siblings are suffering some sort of ailment recently.Can someone tell me what the intentions were of the person that created this/left it at their house.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an invocation to jinn. The numbers in the middle are their names (in the Abjad numbering system). It's not clear what the intention is behind their invocation. It could have been for "protection" or something else. It may have been with good intentions. Either way, it doesn't provide true protection (that only comes from Allah) and it is something forbidden (despite good intentions). The ailments are likely not related to *this* device. But there could be a different thing causing that if someone has contracted with a practitioner of sihr. It is also likely unrelated and has a purely medical cause.

You should dispose of it by reciting Ayat al-Kursi over it a few times, at least 3, and then burning or breaking it down outside.

Whatever evil is designed towards you, the protection is simple. Do the morning and evening adhkar always and recite Quran as much as you can.

Source: My teacher Sh Jallow who is a ruqyah expert.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also my dad was told to dispose of it by putting in a stream/running water. He did that. Is it important to dispose of any photos we may have of it as well? Including this post?

Comment: The names on the sides are of Angels, could be a invocation to those Angels aswell.